# Select option value based on AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to set the returned value using AJAX to a **select** element tag for example
If the user clicks on add button it shows the select tag with the option value that returned from the **AJAX response** and when the user clicks on the add button **again** also it inserts a **new select tag** element with the same value that returned for the previous select element tag and so on.

I believe there is something wrong with the JS code that was bolded, But I can't do it or have any idea about it.

**create-sale.php**

```
<div class="form-group paintsDropdownContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
    
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i></span>
    <select class="selectPaint" id="selectPaint" required>
    
        <option value="">Select Paints</option>

        <?php 

        $item = null;
        $value = null;
        $order = 'id';

        $paints = controllerPaints::ctrShowPaints($item, $value, $order);

        foreach ($paints as $key => $value) {
          echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["description"].'</option>';
        }

        ?>
    </select>


  </div>

</div>
```

**sale.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectPaint').selectize({ normalize: true });       // I need to use selectize in order to be able search inside the dropdown list
 });



$(".salesTable tbody").on("click", "button.addProductSale", function(){

    var datum2 = new FormData();
    datum2.append("getPaints", "ok");

    $.ajax({

        url:"ajax/paints.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datum2,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(answer){


            $(".newProduct").append(
                '<div class="form-group paintsDropdownContainer">'+
                      
                  '<div class="input-group">'+
                    
                    '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i></span>'+
                    '<select class="selectPaint" id="selectPaint" required>'+
                    
                        '<option value="">Select Paints</option>'+
                        // I believe the below line should not be here.
                        $.each (answer, function (answerResult) {

                        '<option value="'+answer[answerResult].id+'">'+answer[answerResult].description+'</option>'         

                        });  

                    '</select>'+
                  '</div>'+
                '</div>'+

                );

        }

      }); 





}); // end function
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think it is because in your ajax response you append another select tag. you just have to append an option tag inside your already define select tag.

Comment: Move that `$.each..` outside append and use some variable to add the option values on each iteration i.e : `options +='<option value="'+answer[answerResult].id+'">'+answer[answerResult].description+'</option>'` and then passed this `options` variable instead of the `$.each` .

Comment: @Swati I tried it but it seems like doesn't work. 
Please help

Comment: Can you edit your question with what you have tried ?

Comment: @Swati I found a solution by typing: `document.querySelector(".paintsDropdownContainer"+counter).appendChild(selectList);
for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = answer[i].id;
    option.text = answer[i].description;
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}
$('#selectPaint'+counter).selectize({ normalize: true });   // apply selectize pluging for the newly select option tag
counter++;
`